# How to print webpage via FGL printer (Boca System)

Tags: javascript, php, bash, printing

I working on website for ticketing system where admins need to print tickets via [Boca printer](http://www.bocasystems.com/driver.php). Problem is that Boca use FGL (Friendly Ghost Language) which is a standard in ticket printing.

Is there some kind "secret" where I can be connected, some javascript, or PHP code with some BASH script what I can use to trigger prnting from web page?

Generaly I have a template in HTML format where I put user informations and barcode dynamicly and that need to be printed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your Boca is connected via a serial port you would have to resort to some underlaying mechanism to communicate to this serial port from a webpage; node-serial (or a java applet if you're into obsolete technologies) would be a solution.

The programming manual is [available here](https://tls-bocasystems.com/pdf/tls-boca-systems-uk-div-programming-guide.pdf) for printing a simple text and cut the ticket you would pass the following command:

`Hello World<p>
(replace <p> by <q> if you don't want it to cut the ticket)`

If your Boca is connected via USB you can print on it via the supplied driver. A solution would be to generate a PDF with the correct ticket's dimensions and then print it out (the user would see the OS print dialog).